# Is it correct to say "a coil is made of many loops"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [loop](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/loop) 1 /luːp/ ●●○ noun [countable]
>
> 1 SHAPE OR LINE a shape like a curve or a circle made by a line
> curving back towards itself, or a piece of wire, string etc that has
> this shape
>
> loop of wire/rope/string etc
>
> A loop of wire held the gate shut.
>
> belt loop (=a loop of material for holding a belt on trousers etc)

I am not sure if "**a coil is made of many loops**".

If it were, would it be correct to say "**I looped the rope around the stick several times to form a coil**" or "**I coiled the rope around the stick into several loops**"?

Also, I am quite confused about the differences between "**to coil**", "**to wind**", "**to twist**", and "**to loop**"?

Comment: A coil need not be made of many loops; it can be made of a few loops.

Comment: We can coil or wind a string, cable etc. round something to store it and prevent it from tangling. We can also coil a rope by making it into a series of loops with nothing in the middle. _To loop something_ is to make a single loop with it. If the rope is twisted [round something], there is an unwanted loop or kink in it. We can also twist two or more lengths of something together to secure them or to maker a thicker cord.

Comment: In electrical engineering, the "loops" of wire or conducting material that make up coils, transformer windings, inductors, etc, are called "turns".